# Add all values of an instance of an object to a List

Tags: java, list, arraylist, tolist

Say i have a class 'Dog' with a lot of String values and i want all of those values in a List, would there be any better way than adding every value by themselves?

e.g. take this dummy class, note that all values are Strings if that matters

```
public class Dog {
    private String breed;
    private String name;
    private String origin;
    [...] a lot more

    getter and setter methods
    }
```

---

```
Dog dog = new Dog([...] bla bla);
```

Would there be any better way to get all those values of an instance into a List than:

```
public List<String> toList() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(dog.getBreed);
    list.add(dog.getName);
    list.add(dog.getOrigin);
    [...]
    return list;
```

Comment: probably `toString` to return all value with `,` as delimiter and after that split into `List`

Comment: If it is case of list, simply write method called `add(String value) {//add to list}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use reflection.

```
Dog dog = new Dog("val1", "val2", "val3");
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Field field: Dog.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
                // since fields are private we need to first mark it accesible
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if( field.getType().equals(String.class)) {
                        list.add((String) field.get(dog));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was super easy for me to understand and everything works!

Answer (score 2):

Using reflection you can give a try to `get` the value of the fields of object:

```
Dog dog = new Dog("labrador","tarzan","uk"); // sample
List<String> values = Arrays.stream(Dog.class.getDeclaredFields())
        .filter(f ->f.getType().equals(String.class))
        .map(f -> {
  try {
    return (String) f.get(dog); // get the value of field from the object
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { 
    return ""; /// handle in a cleaner way
  }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think like this that a dog has several properties or attributes like breed type, origin, name and many more. You can add the values to list also, but it will be better to maintain a map because while retrieving you have to know what you are trying to retrieve.

It will be better to maintain a Map of attributes and actual values. The code may be like this.

```
public class Dog {
    private Map<String,String> attributesMap = new HashMap<>();

    //getter and setter for attributesMap

}
```

You can create instance of Dog class and add the attributes like this.

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.getAttributesMap().put("breed", "some breed");
dog.getAttributesMap().put("origin", "some some origin");

System.out.println("What is the breed type: "+dog.getAttributesMap().get("breed");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly i'm not allowed to change how the values are stored in the class or how the instance are initialized. So this won't work for this task

Comment: Can you explain this line "i'm not allowed to change how the values are stored in the class" so that I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can you json serialization.
Consider below code:

```
List<String> StringFieldList = Arrays.asList("breed", "name", "origin");
Gson gson = new Gson();
Dog dogObject = new Dog();
//set all field(s) value
JsonObject dogJsonObject  = (JsonObject) gson.toJsonTree(dogObject, Dog.class);

for (String field : StringFieldList) {
    String stringFieldValue = dogJsonObject.get(field).getAsString();
    //Add stringFieldValue in list            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not much different from your solution but at least it controls a bit values being returned as List.

```
private List<String> allValues = new ArrayList<>();

public Dog(String breed, String name, String origin) {
   this.breed = setAndReturn(breed);
   this.name = setAndReturn(name);
   this.origin = setAndReturn(origin);
}

private String setAndReturn(String value) {
   if (value != null) {
      allValues.add(value);   
   }
   return value;
}

public List<String> toList() {
   return allValues;
}
```